# Any command to show how many applications are currently running under Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Wondering any command line tool can shows the Tomcat status?

Comment: Did you check the [manager app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html), maybe this is all you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use most of the manager application urls outside of the application.  So to generate a list of running applications you can issue the wget (in linux) command :

```
wget http://{hostname}:{portnumber}/manager/list --http-user=username --http-password=password
```

This will return a list of applications and their running status.

However unless access through the command line is a firm requirement I would recommend researching using the [tomcat manager app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

EDIT:
You can also check the 'status' of the server by using the command:

```
wget http://{hostname}:{portnumber}/manager/status --https-user=username --http-password=password
```

This will return html but a little scripting and you can parse the required values out.

hope that helps

Comment: Is this all there is? Attempting to setup all the requirements just to run an unnecessary web app so one can view running apps seems enormously stupid.