# Way to check status of tomcat apps through command line NOT via Tomcat Manager

Tags: bash, tomcat

I am trying to create a way to automatically check the status of tomcat manager via script and email if there any issues at a certain time. I've searched online and I couldn't find any satisfactory answer on how to do this other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387056/any-command-to-show-how-many-applications-are-currently-running-under-tomcat).

And like one commenter suggested in that page, this does sound tremendously stupid that isn't a way to do this other than going via wget and fetching it like that. I refuse to believe it!

Question is, does anyone know of an easier way?

Comment: It is not stupid at all. You should not check tomcat. It is better to check the application that is running inside tomcat. And this can be done for example with a specific health check page that is polled, for example by using wget

Answer (score 1):

It seems the easiest way I found to do this is the with the following tool:

https://github.com/kotfu/tomcat-manager